# Wrong number of arguments passed

Tags: exception, clojure, arguments

```
(defn make-heavy [f] 
  (fn [& args]
    (Thread/sleep 1000)
    (apply f args)))

(defn doRunThroughSplit [vector NoOfLines]
;the function is too long

(def zzz [34877 30287 18160 22981])
```

they are 4 files with the number of rows

```
(time (def abc (map (make-heavy doRunThroughSplit [x1 n1 m1 b1] zzz))))
```

It seems i keep on getting this exception which i do not understand why

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: final$make-heavy clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

The make heavy function was actually copied from practical clojure.

Comment: Next time, please consider posting code that compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is conceivable that this is what you want:

```
(defn make-heavy [f] (fn [& args] (Thread/sleep 1000) (apply f args)))

(defn doRunThroughSplit [NoOfLines] (println "noOfLines=" NoOfLines))

(def zzz [34877 30287 18160 22981])

(time (def abc (map (make-heavy doRunThroughSplit) zzz)))
```